# Email server requiremtns

Tags: email, exim

Could you please me know server specs for (Centos) machine serving mail for about 500 users. we are planning to configure exim mail server.

what would be the (esp. memory)?

Please advise on it.

Regards,
Muhammad Shahid

Comment: This question is completely out-of-place here!!  You are asking for something that has a very strong tendency to be subjective (in other words 10 different answers from 10 different people and it still may not be right).  You need to work with your department, the business, etc.  Based on the requirements, you need to do your own due diligence.  You cannot ask programmers and scripters to properly size a server!!  I am very sorry!!!

Answer (score -1):

if you want to install only exim mail server on your server you can install it with minimum 2GB RAM and 40GB HDD.